# jquery .find() not finding class

Tags: jquery

I have a part of my html code that goes like this:

```
 <div id="photo-list-container" class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-4 col-md-3">
                    <div class="photo-gallery-holder mar-2x" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".bs-example-modal-lg" data-id="{{ $photo->id }}" data-photo-filename="{{ $photo->id }}" data-tags="{{ htmlspecialchars(json_encode($photo->tags)) }}">
                        <img class="img-responsive" src="{{ $photo->thumb_url }}" alt="{{ $photo->title }}" />
                    </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

and the I have tried to do with jquery:

```
$('#photo-list-container').find('.photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
...
});

OR

$('#photo-list-container .photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
```

And it always returns not found. why is that? The div that im searching for is nested in the photo-list-container just fine?

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: $('#photo-list-container .photo-gallery-holder').each(function(a,b) { ----work for me in your given html code

Comment: check this fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8fn13f75/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#photo-list-container').find('#photo-list-container')` will look inside `#photo-list-container` for `#photo-list-container`. And there will be nothing to find.

Beside this, a `id` should be always unique. So there is no need for `find` or `each` in any case.

If you want to find all `.photo-gallery-holder` inside of the parent `#photo-list-container` you can use `find`. But I would prever to use a direct selector.

```
$('#photo-list-container').find('.photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
    // ...
});

// or better
$('#photo-list-container .photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
    // ...
});
```

Comment: please see my last update of the javascript line.. i misscopied the first time

Comment: is the `id="photo-list-container"` multiple times in your document? As I wrote, `id` is unique! @EdwardMaiden

Comment: Then there is no propblem, @EdwardMaiden See here: https://jsfiddle.net/wf0hm2u7/

Answer (score 1):

you have used `#` it is for id selector you have to use `.` for class selector something like as below

```
$('#photo-list-container').find('.photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
...
});
```

or

```
$('#photo-list-container .photo-gallery-holder').each(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: sorry my bad. That is what i was using.. i misscoppied the line.

Comment: please see my last update of the javascript line.. i misscopied the first time

Answer (score 0):

change the line `$('#photo-list-container').find('#photo-list-container').each(function() {` to `$('#photo-list-container').find('.photo-list-container').each(function() {`

that is, changing `"#"` to `"."`

`#` indicates targeting **element by id**

and `.(dot)` indicates targeting **by class name**

find more jQuery selectors on this link http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

**Post Edit**

Use `$('#photo-list-container .photo-list-container').each(function() {`

check the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/8fn13f75/

Answer (score 0):

You have to just **add class with Id element** as below.
It will first find element with Id and then look for class and find matching element from HTML

```
$('#photo-list-container .photo-gallery-holder').each(function(a,b) {
        .....
});
```

Comment: please see my last update of the javascript line.. i misscopied the first time

Comment: $('#photo-list-conta‌​iner .photo-gallery-holde‌​r').each(function(a,b‌​) { ----work for me in your given html code –

Comment: oh, thanks. Then i guess its f*****g laravel's fault again. somehow